# halterrego bluetooth headset lag

Tags: windows-8, audio, bluetooth, wireless-headset

I just bought a new Halterrego headset (just google halterrego if you want). The problem is that it has about 4~8 seconds latency. I can't watch movies and in games I'm dead way before hearing the bullet.

It has :

- Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR (my laptop supports BT 3.0 I think)
- Profiles : Headset, Hands free, A2DP, AVRCP

In sound properties I found two related playback devices :

- Headphones : Stereo 2 Channel 16 bit 44100Hz   <= The one I use and has the huge lag
- Headset    : Hands-free 1 Channel 8 bit 8000Hz <= Almost no lag but as you probably already guessed, the sound is crappy.

I looked around a bit but it's either phone/ubuntu related, or the issue is similar but I don't get the technical stuff.

Please help.

Thank you.

Edit: My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be a bug in the audio driver. I recently updated it and the problem is solved, although when I put some distance I get lag even if I go back near the computer, so I just turn it off then on and the problem is solved once more.